# How to export multiply data from a .txt and insert into a database

Tags: php, mysql

How can i export multiply data from different text files and import the data into a database?

So i have a database called: **admin_cars** and a table: **brands** ; like:

```
CREATE TABLE `brands` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `bmw` varchar(500) NOT NULL,
  `mercedes` varchar(500) NOT NULL
  `audi` varchar(500) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Now i want to export the data from: **/var/www/html/bmw/index.txt** into -> **bmw**

I have already written the script in **.PHP** and it works fine. This is the code:

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=admin_cars;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'admin_cars';
$password = '********';
 
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
 
$file= new SplFileObject('/var/www/html/bmw/index.txt');
while(!$file->eof())
{
    $line=$file->fgets();
    list($bmw)=explode(';',$line);
    
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO brands values(NULL,?)');
    $sth->bindValue(1,$bmw,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();   
}
 
?>
```

But now i want to export also the data from /var/www/html/mercedes/index.txt into -> mercedes **and** /var/www/html/audi/index.txt into -> audi

I tried this:

```
<?php

$dsn = 'mysql:dbname=admin_cars;host=127.0.0.1';
$user = 'admin_cars';
$password = '********';
 
try {
    $dbh = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
    echo 'Connection failed: ' . $e->getMessage();
}
 
$file= new SplFileObject('/var/www/html/bmw/index.txt');
while(!$file->eof())

$file= new SplFileObject('/var/www/html/mercedes/index.txt');
while(!$file->eof())

$file= new SplFileObject('/var/www/html/audi/index.txt');
while(!$file->eof())

{
    $line=$file->fgets();
    list($bmw)=explode(';',$line);

    $line=$file->fgets();
    list($mercedes)=explode(';',$line);

    $line=$file->fgets();
    list($audi)=explode(';',$line);
    
    $sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO brands values(NULL,?,?,?)');
    $sth->bindValue(1,$bmw,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(2,$mercedes,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->bindValue(3,$audi,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $sth->execute();   
}
 
?>
```

But i get a error message and faults when i run the .PHP script.
What is the best solution to export multiply data into the tables of the database?

Thank you very much for your time and help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using same variable for all files data repeatedly, so maybe that is an issue. For start, try reading them separately and write them to DB with one while loop after another.

```
$file_bmw= new SplFileObject('/var/www/html/bmw/index.txt');
while(!$file_bmw->eof())
{
// input to db
}
$file_mercedes= new SplFileObject('/var/www/html/mercedes/index.txt');
while(!$file_mercedes->eof())
{
// input to db
}
```

What is the error displayed ?

Comment: Thank you. It works! have a blessed night!